# Is the smart contract receiving funds or is it the address?

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache, cpp-ethereum

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.6.12;

contract ExceptionExample {

    mapping(address => uint) public balanceReceived;

    function receiveMoney() public payable {
        balanceReceived[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function withdrawMoney(address payable _to, uint _amount) public {
        if(_amount <= balanceReceived[msg.sender]) {
            balanceReceived[msg.sender] -= _amount;
            _to.transfer(_amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say I deploy a smart contract with address a. Now, when I interact with the function receiveMoney() and send 20 eth. The smart contract is getting the ether right? and, inside that receiveMoney function, it is just increasing the amount that I sent to the address right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. When you call `receiveMoney` with, lets say 1 ETH as value, the smart contract's balance increases by 1 ETH.